# construct dictionary from lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i am just a beginner so please dont mind..

i am looking for this answer, if score in score list is above 60 it should say pass or else fail, i really no getting how to implement it

```
{'steve': [22, 55, 'fail'], 'saul': [59, 85, 'pass'], 'paul': [28, 59, 'fail'], 'chimpy': [5, 60, 'pass']}
```

and i am just a below code with no success

```
def construct_dictionary_from_lists(names_list, ages_list, scores_list):
   dic = {}
   agee = ages_list
   sc = scores_list
   name = names_list
   for i in range(len(name)):
      for a in range(len(agee)):
         for s in range(len(sc)):
             for x in range(len(sc)):
                if x >= 60:
                    print('Pass')
                else:
                    print('Fail')
             dic[name[i]] = [agee[a], sc[s], sc[x]]
   return dic
print(construct_dictionary_from_lists(["paul", "saul", "steve", "chimpy"],[28, 59, 22, 5],[59, 85, 55, 60]))
```

i am getting below OUTPUT

```
Fail
Fail
Fail
{'paul': [5, 60, 60], 'saul': [5, 60, 60], 'steve': [5, 60, 60], 'chimpy': [5, 60, 60]}
```

Comment: Need to clarify where is age list and score_list... in your code...

Comment: @Narendra, see the last line.

Comment: Thanks a lot @codekaiz

Comment: @kiffu, you're welcome. you can accept any answer which is working at your end.

Comment: You should separate out the score check from the dictionary creation - they are not related.  Really they should go into different functions.

Comment: @codekaizer yh i am looking into every answer, but your answer is very clear nd clean to understand

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
def construct_dictionary_from_lists(names_list, ages_list, scores_list):
   dic = {}
   for name, age, score in zip(names_list, ages_list, scores_list):
       res = 'Fail'
       if score >= 60:
          res = 'Pass'
       dic[name] = [age, score, res]
   return dic

print(construct_dictionary_from_lists(["paul", "saul", "steve", "chimpy"],[28, 59, 22, 5],[59, 85, 55, 60]))
```

Comment: `res =  'Pass' if score >= 60 else 'Fail'` maybe, then the whole `for` body is a nice and compact two lines and you don't assign `res` twice in case it's a pass.

Comment: @MichaelKohl, I agree. just for readability since OP said he's a beginner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip`.

```
name_list, age_list, score_list = ["paul", "saul", "steve", "chimpy"], [28, 59, 22, 5], [59, 85, 55, 60]
out = {name: [age, score, 'pass' if score >= 60 else 'fail'] for name, age, score in zip(name_list, age_list, score_list)}
print(out)
# {'paul': [28, 59, 'fail'], 'saul': [59, 85, 'pass'], 'steve': [22, 55, 'fail'], 'chimpy': [5, 60, 'pass']}
```

Comment: key is `name` not `age`

Answer (score 1):

```
n = ["paul", "saul", "steve", "chimpy"]
n2 = [28, 59, 22, 5]
n3 = [59, 85, 55, 60]
d={}
for i in zip(*(n, n2, n3)):
    if i[2] >=60:
        d[i[0]] = [i[1], i[2], "Pass"]
    else:
        d[i[0]] = [i[1], i[2], "Fail"]
print d
```

**Output:**

```
{'steve': [22, 55, 'Fail'], 'paul': [28, 59, 'Fail'], 'chimpy': [5, 60, 'Pass'], 'saul': [59, 85, 'Pass']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function approach

```
name_list, age_list, score_list = ["paul", "saul", "steve", "chimpy"], [28,     
59, 22, 5], [59, 85, 55, 60]
score_list = list(zip(name_list, age_list, score_list))

def construct_dictionary_from_lists(scores_list):
    dict_result = {}
    for item in score_list:
        result = "pass" if item[2] > 60 else "fail"
        dict_result[item[0]] = [item[1], item[2], result]

    return dict_result

construct_dictionary_from_lists(score_dict)
```

Answer (score -1):

If the size of all the lists are the same, then you can use `zip` to create the dictionary:

```
 for name,age,score in zip(name_list,age_list,score_list):
      Add in the dictionary
```

Comment: i will try but how to input pass fail result ? if score is above 60 it should say pass else it should say fail..

Comment: @johnashu i am not giving the exact code but just a hint.

Comment: The hint was fine.. just not formatted and you used foreach.. which is valid psudeocode i know but not really helpful for the beginner.. Its all good :)